# cache problem in actionscript URLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3

In one of my flash project i am getting xml data from the aspx file. But it always shows the same data and the new data is not coming in the request. I suspect the problem is in cache. 
Below is my code

```
var urlloader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(serverPath +
                                         'GetScoreDetails.aspx?CardNo='+CardNo);
fscommand("LOG", serverPath + 'GetScoreDetails.aspx?CardNo=' + CardNo );
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedCompleteHandler);
urlloader.load(urlRequest);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var xmlPath:String="replaceYourXMLPathHere.xml"
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlPath+"?time=" + new Date().getTime());
```

http://www.newtonflash.com/blog/2009/06/08/prevent-xml-caching-problem/#comment-43

Comment: For the record, the solution was to add a different random param to the request url every time it's fetched.

Comment: +1 here, BUT It seems like the mechanism of setting request headers in URLRequest does not work at all! :( I'm using the old Flash 4.0 SDK